How do I make GNOME Remote Desktop scale dynamically based on connecting client's resolution?
I am using a Windows 11 machine as a thin client (B) to RDP to another machine running Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop (A). I enabled GNOME Remote Desktop over RDP as instructed [here]. Now, the issue is that the Ubuntu machine is connected to a widescreen monitor with higher resolution, while the Windows 11 laptop has a much lower resolution. As a result, scrollbars appear inside the RDP window on the Windows client side, even in the full screen mode. This is not only annoying, but also makes the setup unusable. I tried tweaking with the display resolution slider under the "Display" tab of the Windows RDP client. Unfortunately, that just affects the window size, but not the actual resolution.
I cannot use xRDP, because I need to connect to an existing GNOME session on A from B. As far as I understand, xRDP requires all other sessions to be logged out, and it can only connect to existing X-Windows sessions (if configured accordingly).
On a related note, I also connect to another Windows 10 desktop (C) connected to a lower resolution monitor from another Windows 11 desktop (D) client connected to the same widescreen monitor. This setup works flawlessly, i.e., the RDP window on D goes both full-screen and automatically resizes C's desktop.
In other words, the same Windows 11 RDP client works fine with Windows 10's RDP server, but not with Ubuntu 22.04's embedded FreeRDP server. Looking for ideas to dynamically scale the display resolution according to connecting RDP client's (B's) resolution with the GNOME Remote Desktop server on A.
